# Issue on search arabic words using FastPdfKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using `fastPdfKit` to open pdf files in my iPhone app, it is a great kit do search, get bookmarks, go to specific pages and zooming but when I opened an arabic pdf document and tried to search for an arabic word, I found that it searches for just 1 separated character 
is there any solution for this problem ??

Comment: did you resolve this problem ?